# how to put CFGregorianDate in NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c

How do I get a CFGregorianDate (currentSelectDate) into an NSDictionary?

I get this error with the code below:

> Sending 'CFGregorianDate' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

My code:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: currentSelectDate forKey:@"currentSelectDate"];
```

Comment: Okay, so this is a Core Foundation incompatibility.  Have you attempted to use `__bridge` or its ilk?

Comment: I'm not familiar with __bridge... like which "flavor" of __bridge would I use?  (I'm doing a postNotificationName and hoping to xfer the CFGregorianDate to the receiver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CFGregorianDate is basically a C structure. First create a NSData instance to hold its bytes:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&currentSelectDate length:sizeof(CFGregorianDate)];
```

and then place that in your dictionary instead:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:data forKey:@"currentSelectDate"];
```

To retrieve it, let's assume you have a CFGregorianDate allocated (in this case, on the stack), again called `currentSelectDate`:

```
NSData *data = [userInfo objectForKey:@"currentSelectDate"];
[data getBytes:&currentSelectDate length:sizeof(CFGregorianDate)];
```

Best wishes to you in your endeavors.

Comment: Hi Trudy... getting an error on the NSData statement:

"Sending CFGregorianDate to parameter of incompatible type 'const void *'"

Answer (score 1):

This is not a great solution, but if you just need an quick fix why don't you just put the gregorian into a string and then put that into the dictionary? You could even make an individual string from each piece of the data and store those in the different indices of the dictionary.